# SOAPUI: Invalid Foreign Key Relationship name Product2

Tags: soap, xml

I'm trying to upsert an OrderProduct (OriderItem) on my order with below message

```
 <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:upsert>
         <urn:externalIDFieldName>Order_Product_Number_AS400__c</urn:externalIDFieldName>
         <urn:sObjects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="urn1:OrderItem">
         <Product2>
               <Product_Code_AS400__c>01190</Product_Code_AS400__c>
            </Product2>
            <Order>
               <Order_Number_AS400__c>T007</Order_Number_AS400__c>
            </Order>
            <Order_Product_Number_AS400__c>T007.0</Order_Product_Number_AS400__c>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <UnitPrice>401</UnitPrice>
            
         </urn:sObjects>
      </urn:upsert>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Following response is showed

```
  <created>false</created>
            <errors>
               <message>Invalid foreign key relationship name Product2</message>
               <statusCode>INVALID_FIELD</statusCode>
            </errors>
```

When I use Postman and put my request in Json I'm able to upsert my record

```
{
    "Order" : {"Order_Number_AS400__c" : "T007"},
    "Order_Product_Number_AS400__c" : "T007.0",
    "Quantity" : "1",
    "UnitPrice": "401",
    "Product2" : { "Product_Code_AS400__c" : "01190"}
}
```

Anyone an idea what is wrong in the message?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in SOAP when you have a working REST version?

Comment: This was just for myself, our customer is using SOAP calls...